# How to store dynamic value in Variable For Bash?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line-interface, azure-cli

I have below command:

```
ExpirationDate=$(date -d '+60 days' +'%Y-%m-%d')
VaultName="abc"
getapp=$(az keyvault secret list --vault-name $VaultName --query "[].{SecretName:name,ExpiryDate:attributes.expires} [?ExpiryDate<='$ExpirationDate']" | jq '.[].SecretName' | tr -d '"')

getserviceprincipal=$(az keyvault secret list --vault-name $VaultName --query "[].{Type:contentType,ExpiryDate:attributes.expires} [?ExpiryDate<='$ExpirationDate']" | jq '.[].Type' | tr -d '"')
     
## get length of $distro array
len=${#getapp[@]}

## Use bash for loop 
for (( i=0; i-le$len-1; i++ ))
 do 
 echo "${getapp[$i]}" 
  ./resetpassword.sh -a ${getapp[$i]} -s  ${getserviceprincipal[$i]} -y
 echo "${getserviceprincipal[$i]}" 
 done
```

in this command I want store all value of vault name **getapp** and similarly **getserviceprincipal**. Example If I have more then 2 vault in getapp variable then script is not working due to $getapp is not storing variable in array.

Is anyone help me to put out this simple solutions!! Thanks In Advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`readarray -t getapp < <( az keyvault ... | tr -d '"' )` should do the trick here.

Note that this requires newlines to be valid delimiters. If there can be newlines in your data then you'll have to pick a different delimiter with the `-d delim` option. If there isn't any single delimiter that works everywhere then bash may not be the best choice for this.

Comment: Thanks , your solution worked but I got error in for loop ,
for (( i=0; i-le$COUNT; i++ ))
./script.sh: line 63: ((: i -le 1: syntax error in expression (error token is "1")

Comment: I think you intended: `for (( i = 0 ; i < len ; i++ )) ; do`. The C-style for loop accepts standard math operators, but doesn't understand `-le` as a less-than-or-equal-to command like in a Bash test.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jq, I think you could so something like that:

```
declare -a getapp=()
declare -a getserviceprincipal=()

# note: be sure to check that the resulting bash is valid!
eval(az keyvault secret list  \
            --vault-name $VaultName  \
            --query "[].{SecretName:name,ExpiryDate:attributes.expires} [?ExpiryDate<='$ExpirationDate']" \
 | jq --raw-output '.[] | @sh "getapp+=( \(.SecretName) ) ; getserviceprincipal+=( \(.Type) );' ")
```

If all goes well, this will result in `getapp` and `getserviceprincipal` being filled as array: https://jqplay.org/s/BbHMn9i79KB

Note:

- as you can see, you don't need to invoke your command (az) twice.
- you can also extract the jq expression to a file using the `--from-file` option, which may help when reading it and handling shell quotes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , but I got one error ./script.sh: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `az'
 
Error Coming from eval(az keyvault secret list

Comment: You should run without the `eval`: I wrote the script but did not test it against a shell. The array concat syntax (eg: `getapp+=( ... )`) should work but I might have introduced a shell error. I personally use this with `--from-file` as well as `source` + temp bash file to avoid shell oddities.